# Cudafy.net with NSight, "Error decompiling kernel" after debug start

Tags: debugging, compiler-errors, decompiling, cudafy.net

I'm using Cudafy.net for GPU computations. Everything works fine unless I try to debug the kernel using NSight. After NSight->"Start CUDA debugging", this error occurs:

"Error decompiling System.Void
Network.ActivationFunction(Cudafy.GThread, System.Single[])"

After the error the application crashes. I tried even the most simple kernel I could think of like this one (matches to the error):

```
        [Cudafy]
        public static void ActivationFunction(GThread t, float[] x)
        {
            // Synapse idx
            int i = t.blockDim.x * t.blockIdx.y * t.gridDim.x           //rows preceeding current row in grid
                   + t.blockDim.x * t.blockIdx.x                        //blocks preceeding current block
                   + t.threadIdx.x;

            x[i] = 1;
        }
```

I've already searched for solution and found this:
[cudafy.net with NSight, debugger not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612664/cudafy-net-with-nsight-debugger-not-working)
However even after multiple check of all steps, I still can't make the debugger running. I can't even set breakepoint before the app crashes. Maybe there's something wrong with nvcc or cl? Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error because the working directory for NSight was not set correctly.  You need to set it where the executable for your application is actually running -- when debugging that is typically the debug directory (i.e. C:\somepath\yourproject\bin\Debug).

You set this value via the "NSight User Properties" button in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer jpreed00. Setting the debug directory solved my problem together with updating the version of NSight to the most recent one.

Comment: Great!  Don't forget to select this as the answer, then.  :)